# Как создать локальных пользователей на коммутаторе QSR-1920-12-AC с разными уровнями доступа

Tags: switch

Как создать локальных кользователей на коммутаторе QSR-1920-12-AC с разными уровнями доступа?
Нужно настроить Network-admin и Network-operator

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Создание локальных пользователей на маршрутизаторах одинаково на QSR-1920/2920/3920

Создание пользователей на маршрутизаторах – это неотъемлемая часть настройки безопасности сети, если не используется удаленный ААА-сервер.

RBAC (управление доступом на основе ролей). Основная идея RBAC — указать роли для пользователей. Эти роли определяют, какие функции системы и ресурсные объекты, с которыми пользователям разрешено работать.

По умолчанию существует четыре роли: Security-admin, Network-admin, Audit-admin и Network-operator. Полномочия этих четырех ролей не могут быть изменены.

Таблица соответствий полномочий ролей пользователей:
[image: Таблица соответствий полномочий ролей пользователей]

**Посмотреть локальных пользователей:**

```
QSR#show users class manager
```

либо:

```
QSR#show running-config | include local-user
```

Создание пользователя NAME c уровнем привилегий 15, паролем PASSWORD123 и доступом к службам SSH TELNET HTTP HTTPS:

```
QSR#configure terminal

QSR(config)#local-user NAME class manager

QSR(config-user-manager-NAME)#privilege 15

QSR(config-user-manager-NAME)#service-type ssh telnet web

QSR(config-user-manager-NAME)#password 0 PASSWORD123

QSR(config-user-manager-NAME)#user-role network-admin
```

**Конфигурирование локальной авторизации, чтобы применить эффект роли пользователя:**

```
QSR(config)#domain system

QSR(config-isp-system)#aaa authentication login local

QSR(config-isp-system)#aaa authorization login local
```

**После этого необходимо настроить терминал для авторизации пользователей:**

```
QSR(config)#line vty 0 15
QSR(config)#login aaa
```

**Пароль для доступа в привилегированный режим:**

```
QSR(config)#enable password 0 PASSWORD123
```

**Включение ssh-сервера:**

```
QSR(config)#ip ssh server
```

**Включение HTTPS-сервера:**

```
QSR(config)#ip http secure-server
```

Пройдя авторизацию в веб-интерфейсе, на вкладке System -> User Management можно добавлять, удалять и редактировать пользователей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В окне добавления нового пользователя заполняем логин и пароль, а также указываем, к каким сервисам будет доступ у данной учетной записи, и задаем уровень доступа (администратор или пользователь):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, благодаря определенным ролям, каждый пользователь будет иметь доступ только к тем ресурсам и функциям, которые необходимы для выполнения его задач. Благодаря четко установленным привилегиям, мы можем уверенно предоставлять возможности администрирования и мониторинга, минимизируя риски несанкционированного доступа.

Кроме того, мы обеспечили безопасный способ удаленного подключения с использованием SSH, а также защитили веб-интерфейс через HTTPS. Это снижает риски перехвата данных при удаленном управлении маршрутизаторами.

С настройкой локальной авторизации и учетных записей пользователей через веб-интерфейс, мы создали удобную и эффективную систему управления пользователями. Теперь администраторы смогут быстро реагировать на изменения, добавлять новых пользователей, редактировать доступ и роли, всегда имея контроль над безопасностью сети.

Таким образом, завершив описанные шаги, мы успешно настроили надежную систему управления доступом, обеспечивая высокий уровень безопасности и эффективное администрирование нашей сети на маршрутизаторах QSR-1920/2920/3920.

[Источник информации по настройке](https://www.qtech.ru/education/articles/sozdanie-lokalnykh-polzovateley-na-marshrutizatorakh-qsr-1920-2920-3920/)